# Do the 2 individual 120v legs coming from meter into main panel have to be connected to specific terminals on the main shutoff breaker?

Tags: electrical, wiring, electrical-panel

The old SEU wiring in my box has a black and red cable, but I have also seen newer SEU service cable where both 120v legs were black.

Answer (score 8):

No, there is no "positive or negative" or "left and right" or whatever.  This is the same when hooking up a 240v appliance.  The two legs don't matter and there is often no way to differentiate the legs other than maybe black and red.

Comment: NO PHASING REQUIRED AS WOULD BE WITH THREE PHASE..+

Comment: I assumed there was no specific order for single phase, but better to ask the community and get a consensus. I'm actually surprised that in roughly an hour of Google searching I could not find any forum/blog/article that specifically touched upon this exact topic.

Comment: Yeah I know.  I have an installation with 2 conduits between the panel and the machine shop.  One conduit has 20A circuits. The other conduit has four 30A circuits arranged B-R, B-R, B-R, and B-R.  *In the bottom of the panel and splice box are a bunch of wire markers that fell off*. Imma rearrange them B-B, R-R conduit 1, B-B, R-R conduit 2.

Answer (score 7):

Yeah, in split-phase, nobody cares what color the hots are.

I've seen people go in backflips to have red and black. It's just not necessary.

Of course in cables, it's best-practice to do *something* to distinguish conductors.  You never know what the application will be.